# How can I prevent a SpeedDialAction that opens dialog from refocusing the SpeedDial when the dialog is closed?

Tags: material-ui, react-dropzone

I have a `SpeedDialAction` (@material-ui/lab@4.0.0-alpha.56) that opens a file dialog.  If you choose one or more files it opens a material-ui modal dialog.  It's using `react-dropzone`, but I don't know if that's relevant here.  At the beginning of the action click handler I set the `open` state on the `SpeedDial` to `false`, and it closes.  When you:

- cancel the file dialog
- cancel the material-ui dialog
- submit from the material-ui dialog

...afterwards the `SpeedDial` component's `onOpen` callback is called, and passed `'focus'` as the reason.  I'm not sure why this is happening or really which component is driving this behavior.  Is there an easy way to suppress this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in the [docs](https://material-ui.com/api/modal/#props): the `disableRestoreFocus` prop on `Modal`, which is inherited by `Dialog`.